# Maintaining history of previous searches

Tags: java, mysql

I am doing a project, where customers can find the nearest places to him which he can buy some specific products.He requests the service by sending an SMS.

Here I need to maintain the history of previous searches by other customers and reply to the current customers efficiently using this history.

Is there any efficient way to maintain the history and also it needs to be updated as well.
I am using Java and MySQL.Is there a way to use knowledge base concept here?If yes how to apply knowledge base to our system?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table of records (in database, memory cache etc) containing these fields:
(Request, Response, Timestamp), and before doing full search check this table. When you change anything in main database, all linked records should be renamed from this temporary table. When it is required, you can remove records from your history.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.Is there any way to do this task intelligently?That means I may not get the exact same request from a new customer.Is there a way to select some likely earlier requests?

Comment: @user1516566, you should define similarity measure for your requests, for example, if 50% of words in requests are the same, than use answer from history, or something else. It depends on your requirements.